# Anime about super athletes breaking world records

Tags: story-identification, anime

I recently watched part of an anime episode on my Roku. It was late and I was tired so I turned it off and went to bed. Now I can't remember the name of the anime. It was probably on Crunchyroll since that's the one I usually watch, but I do occasionally watch the other anime channels available on Roku.

It had something to do with super athletes breaking world records in various events like high jump and track & field. I can't remember if they were born with these extra physical abilities or if they were experimented on and somehow modified to enhance their physical abilities.

Also, I seem to recall some shadowy, behind-the-scenes group of people who knew what was going on with these super athletes and how they were able to break these records so easily. This group may have had something to do with it. I'm not sure.

Anyway, I hope that's enough information for somebody to recognize it. All my search attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's *[Black Jack: The Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106421/)*.

> Joe Carol Brain attempts to hire Dr. Black Jack on a breed of superhumans that have the strength, intellectual, athletic, and artistic skills with great excel in different fields, only to later find out that they start deteriorating after some period of time and causing an untimely death. Joe needs Dr. Black Jack's help on finding a cure.

### Trailer

Comment: There's a bit more context in the clip at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90vvRBwVy4I