Gloomy anime about suicidal athletes
My friend trying to find an anime that featured a lot of violence.
The theme was an experiment on athletes aimed to improve their characteristics using experimental medicine.
All of it took place in a building that resembled a mental hospital with depressive surrounding.
The athletes living there were going crazy. The remarkable scene that my friend was able to see, right before his irritated parents turned off the TV, was of a sleeping guy who dreamed about doing very well in the marathon. Instantly he jumped off the bed, ran into the wall, and splashed his brain graphically all over the place.
My friend saw it over 10 years ago, so it should be quite old anime.
He asked a lot about it and couldn't find it. He was impressed by the answer to my previous question and wants to take a chance

Can't really see how is that a duplicate

If it was older looking it may have been Black Jack: The Movie, where the main character is hired to find a cure for why some of the best athletes have been offing themselves or otherwise in poor health. One of which wakes up and runs into a wall.
Here is the scene I think you might be referring to:




If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250913/anime-about-super-athletes-breaking-world-records/250914#250914
